# Setting up PHPUnit tests in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.1

I'm fairly new to unit testing, but I've read pretty much all the documentation on [phpunit.de](http://phpunit.de) (Up to chapter 10).

It states that testing using databases can be slow, but if setup correctly, it can be just as fast as non-database testing.

As such, I want to test a model in Laravel. I've created a model factory to seed data into the database.

I've also created a basic test.

In PHPUnits documentation, it states that before every test, the `setUp()` method is called to setup the test. There's also another static method `setUpBeforeClass()`.

I want to seed my database table only once, and use the records within my test. So I used Laravels `factory()` function to seed the database from within the `setUpBeforeClass()` method.

This is my code:

```
class CommentTest extends TestCase
{
    protected static $blog;
    protected static $comments;

    public static function setUpBeforeClass()
    {
        parent::setUpBeforeClass();

        self::$blog = factory(App\Models\Content\Blog::class)->create();
        self::$comments = factory(App\Models\Content\Comment::class, 6)->create();
    }

    public function testSomething()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

However, when I run `phpunit`, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function make() on a non-object in \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php on line 54

Call Stack:
    0.0002     240752   1. {main}() \vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:0
    0.0173    1168632   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() \vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:47
    0.0173    1175304   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() \vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:100
    2.9397    5869416   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() \vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:149
    2.9447    6077272   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() \vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php:440
    2.9459    6092880   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() \vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestSuite.php:747
    2.9555    6096160   7. call_user_func:{\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestSuite.php:697}() \vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestSuite.php:697
    2.9555    6096272   8. CommentTest::setUpBeforeClass() \vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestSuite.php:697
    2.9555    6096480   9. factory() \tests\CommentTest.php:18
    2.9556    6096656  10. app() \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php:350
```

If I move the code from `setUpBeforeClass()` to `setUp()` and run it, it works as expected, but surely this is inefficient as its seeding the database for every test?

**My questions:**

1. Is seeding the database from within the `setUpBeforeClass()` the correct way to do this?
2. If it is (question 1), then why am I getting the fatal error when running phpunit, and is there anything I should be doing before calling `factory()`?
3. If I do have to place the code in the `setUp()` method, are there going to be performance issues?
4. Should I even be seeding from the `setUpBeforeClass()` or `setUp()` methods? In Laravels documentation it shows examples where the seeding is happening in the test itself, but If i'm running 100 tests (for example), is it a good idea to be seeding 100 times?

Answer (score 28):

Ok, after a bit of investigating (the classes), I've determined that the Laravel application has not yet been created when the static `setUpBeforeClass()` method is called.

The Laravel container is created the first time `setUp()` is called in `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase.php`. That's why it works fine when I move my code to the `setUp()` method.

The container is then stored in the `$app` property stored in `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\illuminate\Foundation\Testing\ApplicationTrait.php`.

I can manually create a container instance by adding this code to the `setUpBeforeClass()` method:

```
$app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
$app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class)->bootstrap();
```

But this method seems pretty hacky, and I don't like it.

Instead, I moved the seeding code to the `setUp`() method, but only seeded the database if the class properties were null. Therefore it only gets seeded on the first call of `setUp()`. Any subsequent calls do not get seeded:

```
class CommentTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    protected static $blog;
    protected static $comments;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->runDatabaseMigrations();

        if (is_null(self::$blog)) {
            self::$blog = factory(App\Models\Content\Blog::class, 1)->create();
            self::$comments = factory(App\Models\Content\Comment::class, 6)->create();
        }
    }
}
```

In combination with Laravels `DatabaseMigrations` trait for testing, This is now the workflow:

1. PHPUnit is called
2. The Test class is called, which contains the `DatabaseMigrations` trait
3. The database is migrated (tables created)
4. The `setUp()` method is called for the first time, which seeds the relevant tables with testing data
5. The test is run, and and access the test data
6. There is no `tearDown()` method invoked, instead the `DatabaseMigrations` trait simply resets the database, so my test doesn't have to worry about cleaning up the test data.

**EDIT**

In addition, it seems (although I'm not 100%), that if you have a custom `setUp()` method, you need to manually call `runDatabaseMigrations()` from the overridden `setUp()` method:

```
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    $this->runDatabaseMigrations();

    /** Rest of Setup **/
}
```

`runDatabaseMigrations()` doesn't seem to get called automatically if you overload the `setUp()` method.

I hope this helps, but if anyone else has a better solution, please feel free to let me know :)

Comment: Phil, any ideas why "runDatabaseMigrations" doesn't get triggered when setUp is overloaded? I have looked through the code and cannot seem to fathom why?

Comment: @Matt Unfortunately I'm not sure why! (If my assumption is even correct). I've had a look through the code as well and can't figure it out either :( This issue is also referenced in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33584071/laravel-databasetransactions-databasemigrations-have-no-effect-when-testing

Comment: Thank You!!  I had just run into this issue myself and was wondering why the application was not setup prior to setUpBeforeClass.  I was tracing the code as well and about to create a SO question myself until I found this :)

Comment: @JosephCrawford glad it helps :)

Comment: The only problem I found is when using the setUp method to create factory models with faker data events that are thrown are no longer seen as thrown when they are.  I have added debugging code to my listener and it is triggered, yet expectsEvents thinks not.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36090425/laravel-5-2-event-testing-expectsevent-not-seeing-the-event-fired-although-it-i

Comment: I started to test the runDatabaseMigrations problem mentioned, but as noted https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/231213d5f8ef9779e25af61dcedea0a0984b3cf9 it has been fixed in 5.2

Comment: @DustinGraham Nice! Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this post! It helped me solve my problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57418323/766570

Comment: Thanks again from 2019! Was scratching my head with ths one - but this solved it